# Complex integration with paramaterisation

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

$\int z\sin(z^2)dz $ where $\gamma(t):= \sqrt{3}t + 2(1-t)i,$ where $0<= t<=1$.
I found this question on a previous years problem sheet but have never seen a question of this format(using parametrisation), how is this different to a 'typical' Cauchy Integral question and how do you go about solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gamma$ is not a loop, you can't use that theorem. Instead, use the fact that $-\frac12\cos(z^2)$ is a primitive of the function that you want to integrate.

Comment: Once the primitive is found, how do I apply Cauchy-Goursat's theorem to this?

Comment: You don't. If $F$ is the primitive, then the integral is equal to $F\bigl(\gamma(1)\bigr)-F\bigl(\gamma(0)\bigr)$.